# how to implement Views in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I've used [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) sample code to create a sliding menu using navigation drawrer. 
I have now the pages of this menu that are `Fragment`. Now I need to put View elements in these pages like buttons textviews, etc. How do I do this? As I'm not in an Activity class, I cant put view elements in the `Fragment`. I've read that i have to create an activity that comunicates with the fragment and does the work. How is this done? can you please show me some sample code? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: Did you read the official documentation? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
You have all the details and one example. Try to work starting from that and then ask here if you have a specific problem.

Comment: You can initialize Button and TextViews. I'll post something as an answer.

Comment: ok, thanks! i'll read the guide and hope to understand everything better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the code below. It has initlialized Button and an ArrayAdapter.
Some things to remember with fragments :

In fragments, you have to use "getActivity()" instead of context.

When writing "findViewById", you have to use instance of View as shown in the code.

This will help you start.

**e.g.**

public class FragmentExample extends Fragment {

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,
                false);

        // String[] valuesD = getResources().getStringArray(
        // R.array.amtsDestination);
        // ArrayAdapter<String> destinationArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        // this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        // valuesD);
        // destinationArray
        // .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        // destination.setAdapter(startArray);

        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonRoute);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", 6000).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was writing my answer but Dhaval did it before ant his is great. 
Anyways, I recommend to visit this great fragment tutorial on fragments 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html from vogella, so you can understand every concept better.

Comment: I used the same tutorial. It's really great.